# Downgrade Kernel 5.19 to 5.15

Tags: drivers, kernel, freeze, amdgpu, downgrade

I'm having issues with my GPU on my laptop after installing ubuntu 22.10 with the 5.19 kernel ("VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00140051"). My Lapotp freezes after a while and I'm also not sure when or how to reproduce this, those freezes come in randomly. Apparently it's a common problem known for ideapad 3 laptops with amd gpu. One suggestion was to downgrade the kernel. Does anybody know a well-explained guide, something beginner-friendly on how to downgrade the kernel from 5.19 to 5.15 without deleting the entire SSD and clean installing an LTS version of the OS?

Edit: Related to the freezes i experience, this is the error/warning I get:

```
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [mmhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32776, for process spotify pid 13673 thread spotify:cs0 pid 13735)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106a20000 from IH client 0x12 (VMC)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00140051
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: MP1 (0x0)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x5
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [mmhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32776, for process spotify pid 13673 thread spotify:cs0 pid 13735)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106a20000 from IH client 0x12 (VMC)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00140051
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: MP1 (0x0)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x5
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [mmhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32776, for process spotify pid 13673 thread spotify:cs0 pid 13735)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106a20000 from IH client 0x12 (VMC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic
```

Then, reboot the computer and choose the kernel in the grub menu.